# Spring Boot cors configuration allows all sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm trying to make my frontend only place from request to backend can be made. Problem is that it doesn't work and every request is being invoked. Below is code which configures Spring Security and cors.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/groups").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://192.168.0.16:8080"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: While this could be possible, I would rather recommend deploying your frontend app on the same host where your backend is. This would NOT require CORS to be enabled on backend, and you can actually disable cross -origin-resource-sharing as you stated in the question that you want to STOP OTHERS except the frontend. This would not make any preflight requests (i.e. OPTIONS).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add `OPTIONS` http method to the `CORS` allowed methods. Most of the front end languages sent an `OPTIONS` request before sending the real one. Something like

```
configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
```